# How to test user login page?

Tags: symfony, phpunit, fosuserbundle

I have installed FosUserBundle and I want to make a test with PhpUnit to check whether users can login, but my code must be wrong, because I can not get redirected.

My code:

```
public function testLogin()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/crm/login');
        $buttonCrawlerNode = $crawler->selectButton('_submit');
        $form = $buttonCrawlerNode->form();
        $data = array('_username' => 'root','_password' => 'toor');
        $client->submit($form,$data);
        $crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/crm/home');
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you are using a different client instance? `$this->client->followRedirect();` -> `$client->followRedirect();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're using 2 different instances of `client`

```
public function testLogin()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/crm/login');
    $buttonCrawlerNode = $crawler->selectButton('_submit');
    $form = $buttonCrawlerNode->form();
    $data = array('_username' => 'root','_password' => 'toor');
    $client->submit($form,$data);

    //here you're using $this->client not $client
    $crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/crm/home');
}
```